# Iterate JSON using Java

Tags: java, json

Below is the JSON response that I have received. I am looking to iterate through the JSON response and retrieve the **taskId** if the status is NEW. Can someone assist me in writing this in Java with org.json? The validation process relies on groovy or xslt . I am looking for someone who can assist me in resolving this issue.Below the code I am trying but it is not working. Before I was trying with Groovy. But now requirement changed I need to use org.json

output should be **221**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;  
import org.json.JSONObject;  
  
// create JSONExample class to iterate JSON Array  
public class JSONExample{  
    //main() method start  
    public static void main(String args[]){      
        // create an string of JSON data  
    String jsonData="{"
            + "    \"document-payload\": ["
            + "        {"
            + "            \"document-name\": \"taskDetails\","
            + "            \"payload\": {"
            + "                \"attributes\": ["
            + "                    {"
            + "                        \"name\": \"status\","
            + "                        \"value\": \"CLOSED\""
            + "                    },"
            + "                    {"
            + "                        \"name\": \"message\","
            + "                        \"value\": \"\""
            + "                    },"
            + "                    "
            + "                    {"
            + "                        \"name\": \"taskId\","
            + "                        \"value\": \"218\""
            + "                    }"
            + "                    "
            + "                ]"
            + "            },"
            + "            \"created\": \"2024-03-07 22:00:49.695202\","
            + "            \"modified\": \"2024-03-07 22:00:49.695202\","
            + "            \"headers\": {"
            + "                \"taskName\": \"Testing\""
            + "            }"
            + "        },"
            + "        {"
            + "            \"document-name\": \"taskDetails\","
            + "            \"payload\": {"
            + "                \"attributes\": ["
            + "                    {"
            + "                        \"name\": \"status\","
            + "                        \"value\": \"NEW\""
            + "                    },"
            + "                    {"
            + "                        \"name\": \"message\","
            + "                        \"value\": \"\""
            + "                    },"
            + "                    "
            + "                    {"
            + "                        \"name\": \"taskId\","
            + "                        \"value\": \"221\""
            + "                    }"
            + "                    "
            + "                ]"
            + "            },"
            + "            \"created\": \"2024-03-07 22:00:49.695202\","
            + "            \"modified\": \"2024-03-07 22:00:49.695202\","
            + "            \"headers\": {"
            + "                \"taskName\": \"Testing\""
            + "            }"
            + "        }"
            + "]"
            + "}";
           String data = jsonData.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    System.out.println(data);
    
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject parent = jobj.getJSONObject("payload");
        JSONArray jarr = parent.getJSONArray("attributes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < jarr.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject test1 = jarr.getJSONObject(j);
                System.out.println(test1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 is not a good tool to process JSON. Either upgrade to XSLT 3.0 or look for another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it that way:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(rawJson) // creates JSON object

def taskIds = json.'document-payload'.payload.findResults{ p -> 
    p.attributes.any{ it.name == 'status' && it.value == 'NEW' } ? p.attributes.find{ it.name == 'taskId' }.value : null 
}

assert taskIds == ['218']
```

if you need a single `taskId`, use `findResult` instead of `findResults`.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume all the `attributes` have unique `name` fields (for each document), then you can do:

```
def listOfNewIds = json."document-payload"
    .payload
    .attributes*.collectEntries { [it.name, it.value] }
    .findAll { it.status == "NEW" }
    .taskId
```

To get a list of Strings containing the `NEW` taskIds